# proper way for sed in windows environment

Tags: unix, sed, cygwin

I have the following sed which works perfect but I do not like the flow because it outputs the result every line.  The second portion of code represents what I am trying to consolidate but the output is not correct.  Can anyone assist?  This piece of code in the second portion is throwing my result out of wack -i -e ":a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g" it works fine in the top code but i can not add it in the second code witout writing out the result set.  I am just trying to write this correctly.

```
sed -i "1,275d" ConedScrape_494202320000008.txt
sed -i -r "s/>/>~/g; s/</~</g;" ConedScrape_494202320000008.txt
sed -i -r "s/~~//g" ConedScrape_494202320000008.txt
sed -i -e :a -e "s/<[^>]*>//g;/</N;//ba" ConedScrape_494202320000008.txt
sed -i "s/\s/\n/g" ConedScrape_494202320000008.txt
sed -i -n -e ":a" -e "$ s/\n/ /gp;N;b a" ConedScrape_494202320000008.txt
sed -i -e "s/^[ \t]*//" ConedScrape_494202320000008.txt
sed -i -e "s/\r//" ConedScrape_494202320000008.txt
sed -i -e "s/&nbsp;*/,/g; s/--*/--,/g" ConedScrape_494202320000008.txt
sed -i -e "s/   //g; s/If you have any problems or questions please contact us at     ~RETAILACCESS@Coned.Com//g;" ConedScrape_494202320000008.txt
sed -i -r "s/,//g; s/~~,/,/g; s/~~/,/g;" ConedScrape_494202320000008.txt
sed -i -r "s/, /,/g; s/,~/,/g;" ConedScrape_494202320000008.txt
sed -i -r "s/,,/,/g; s/~  ,//g;" ConedScrape_494202320000008.txt
sed -i -r "s/,,/,/g" ConedScrape_494202320000008.txt
sed -i -r "s/,, , , ,If you have any problems or questions please contact us at ,RETAILACCESS@Coned.Com,,//g" ConedScrape_494202320000008.txt
sed -i -r "s/,,/,/g; s/, ,//g; s/,Tension Code,Stratum Variable,ICAP,PFJ ICAP,Residential %%,LBMP Zone//g; s/,Trip Number,Service Class,Previous Account Number,Min Monthly Demand,TOD Code,Profile,Tax,Muni//g; s/,From Date,To Date,Use,Demand,Bill Amt//g;" ConedScrape_494202320000008.txt
sed -i -r "s/, //g;" ConedScrape_494202320000008.txt
```

second Portion of code.

```
@echo off
sed -i -e "1,275d" ^
-r -e "s/>/>~/g; s/</~</g;" ^
-e "s/~~//g" ^
-e :a -e "s/<[^>]*>//g;/</N;//ba" ^
-e "s/\s/\n/g" ConedScrape_494202320000008.txt
sed -i -e ":a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g" ConedScrape_494202320000008.txt
sed -i -e "s/^[ \t]*//" ^
-e "s/\r//" ^
-e "s/&nbsp;*/,/g; s/--*/--,/g" ^
-e "s/,//g; s/~~,/,/g; s/~~/,/g;" ^
-e "s/\n/ /g;" ^
-e "/^$/d" ^
-e "s/^\([^,]*,\)\{2\}//" ^
-e "s/,Tension Code,Stratum Variable,ICAP,PFJ ICAP,Residential %%,LBMP Zone//g" ^
-e "s/,Trip Number,Service Class,Previous Account Number,Min Monthly Demand,TOD   Code,Profile,Tax,Muni//g" ^
-e "s/,From Date,To Date,Use,Demand,Bill Amt//g;" ^
-e "s/, /,/g;" ^
-e "s/ ,/,/g;" ^
-e "s/,,//g;" ^
-e "s/, , ,If you have any problems or questions please contact us  at,RETAILACCESS@Coned.Com//g;" ConedScrape_494202320000008.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large number of sed commands, you can put them into a file and use:

```
$ cat script.sed
s/foo/bar/g
s/xxx/yyy/g

$ sed -i -f script.sed data.txt
```